# Update statusItem Title

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstatusitem

How can I update my statusItem Title?
At the moment I do it with a timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(myVoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and the void is:

```
-(void)myVoid {

statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
[statusItem setTitle:myString];

}
```

The content of `myString` changes. How can I update the Title? At the moment, when I update it there comes another statusItem and another and another...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the statusItem once and keep a reference to it in an ivar, then `setTitle` on that rather than creating a new statusItem each time (`statusItemWithLength:` creates a new item).

Comment: Thanks. You solved my problem. But can you say me, how can I make, that I can click on it?

Comment: It depends what you want your statusItem to do... If you want a menu to appear then crate that menu in a NIB and set it on your statusItem using `setMenu:`, for a custom view, use `setView:`

Comment: I wrote an App that shows the temperature in the menu bar, but I must give it a quit button and for that I need a menu